# setting line thickness for a graph - Achart engine

Tags: android-layout, achartengine

I am using AchartEngine for my android phone applications. Everything looks fine but the thickness of a line for the rendered graphs does not appeared to be good. I wanted to increase the thickness for these graphs.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

OK, I got the answer. It should be something like below:

```
        int length = renderer.getSeriesRendererCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            XYSeriesRenderer seriesRenderer = (XYSeriesRenderer) renderer
                    .getSeriesRendererAt(i);                
            seriesRenderer.setLineWidth(2f);
        }
```

Comment: You should also take today's full HD display into account. LineWidth is in pixels, so recompute them by pixel density. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263250/convert-pixels-to-sp

Comment: setLineWidth i could not find this function plz help