# Convert pixels to sp

Tags: android, textview

I need the current `TextSize` of the `TextView` in `sp` units.

But `getTextSize()` returns the size in `pixels`. So is there a way to `convert pixels to sp`?

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42108115/3681880) for `DP -> PX`, `PX -> DP`, `SP to PX`, and `PX to SP` conversions.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

See the [DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#) class, it has fields for `densityDpi` and `scaledDensity`.

Example usage:

```
float sp = px / getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
```

Comment: Just to clarify: the `DisplayMetrics` class has _fields_ `densityDpi` and `scaledDensity`, not methods. And for scaling, one would want to use the `density` field rather than `densityDpi`.

Comment: Please answer the question asked. Saying the name of a class that can be used for an answer is not itself an answer.

Answer (score 146):

Use this

```
public static float pixelsToSp(Context context, float px) {
    float scaledDensity = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
    return px/scaledDensity;
}
```

If you wanna test if this method works right use this snippet

XML

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtHelloWorld"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtHelloWorld2"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
```

Java

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
TextView helloWorldTextView = (TextView)    rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtHelloWorld);
TextView helloWorldTextView2 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtHelloWorld2);
helloWorldTextView2.setTextSize(pixelsToSp(getActivity(), helloWorldTextView.getTextSize()));
```

Both TextView's font size should be same.

Answer (score 5):

weird to see public field that is adjusted at run time but it works. Standard Dpi is 160 so whatever your device Dpi is, say 240, both density and scaledDensity will show 240/160=1.5
This is how you convert between pixels and sp: px=1.5*sp