# Convert 40px to sp

Tags: android

What is the sp value for 40px? Please also tell the formula of conversion.

I am trying to convert my font sizes present in psd into sp units for mdpi density i.e. 320*480 with 160 dpi

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/q/2025282/185655

Comment: @abdel it doesnt answer my question. I need formula for converting px into sp

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263250/convert-pixels-to-sp

Comment: @palejandro I saw that question but still accepted answer was not proper one. I need formula for it. like sp = px*scaledDesnity

Comment: Good tool for that is: http://angrytools.com/android/pixelcalc/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
case COMPLEX_UNIT_SP:
     return value * metrics.scaledDensity;
```

*from the [TypedValue.applyDimension()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/util/TypedValue.java#TypedValue.applyDimension%28int,float,android.util.DisplayMetrics%29) source*

This converts sp to px, just transpose it and you get the formula for converting px to sp:

```
sp = px / DisplayMetrics.scaledDensity
```

Answer (score 2):

```
px = dp * (dpi / 160)
```

This doesn't convert your sp to px or vice versa. But, sp and dp are almost similar, and hence, I think it's safe to use this formula.

> ***Density-independent pixel (dp)***
>       A virtual pixel unit that you should use when defining UI layout, to express layout dimensions or position in a density-independent way.
>
> The density-independent pixel is equivalent to one physical pixel on
>   a 160 dpi screen, which is the baseline density assumed by the system
>   for a "medium" density screen. At runtime, the system transparently
>   handles any scaling of the dp units, as necessary, based on the actual
>   density of the screen in use. The conversion of dp units to screen
>   pixels is simple: `px = dp * (dpi / 160)`. For example, on a 240 dpi
>   screen, 1 dp equals 1.5 physical pixels. You should always use dp
>   units when defining your application's UI, to ensure proper display of
>   your UI on screens with different densities.

*Source*: [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#terms).