# CSS Elements change physical size on higher density screens

Tags: android, css, jquery-mobile

I am developing an Android app with phonegap and pixel density is being a problem. I developed the app using a 4.0" screen that was 320px by 480px. Obviously all is fine, elements are sized using the pixel unit in css.

I was told that pixels in CSS are just a unit and change on high density screens. However I tested the app on a friends 4.0" phone. His phone was 480px by 800px. A higher screen resolution. But everything in the app is tiny, buttons are far too small to click on.

So my question is how best do I go about dealing with this. Is there settings I can use in the Android manifest? Or should I change the Units in CSS (That could take a while).

What is the standard way of dealing with this situation with html and css powered Android apps?

If it helps I am using jquery mobile, with alot of overriden styles.

Answer (score 1):

Use media queries and/or use percentage values instead of fixed pixel values.
Check this article about responsive design http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design

Answer (score 1):

You can also convert from display independent units (e.g. dp or sp) to pixels, based on the device display resolution, and then use CSS in the WebView style sheets that use the resulting pixel widths.
This previous article explains how to convert between [pixel and sp units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263250/convert-pixels-to-sp). You can do the same for dp.

This lets you choose dp or sp units for buttons, text, table column widths, etc. and have WebView render these at a consistent size independent of the display resolution.

So, e.g., the head of your HTML might be

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>This is my title</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            p { font-size: 20px;  }
        </style>
```

and, instead of hard-coding 20px, you compute the pixel size at runtime based on the display resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use media queries

Check the following links to get started

http://www.andreasnorman.com/css-media-queries-for-mobile-devices/

http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/