# setTextSize - sets the text bigger than expected

Tags: android, eclipse, text, text-size

I use this code to set my text by one sp bigger but It increases the size too much...

```
public void doThis(MenuItem item){
        size = text.getTextSize();
        text.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, (float) (size + 1));

    }
```

I want it to add only one sp...

thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you obtain your size in pixels and use it to translate to sp. First you need to convert size back to sp:

```
float scaledDensity = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
float sizeNew = text.getTextSize() / scaledDensity; // obtain current size in sp
sizeNew += 1f; // add 1 sp
text.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, sizeNew); // set new size in sp
```

Comment: @Vyger and only when text scaling is set to normal by user's preferences

Answer (score 1):

You are getting pixels instead of sp from `getTextSize();`

Try this:

```
text.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, (text.getSize() / getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity) + 1);
```

Comment: you need to add casting to float, otherwise value can be wrong

Comment: sorry I am wrong... getTextSize() returns float, not int. So casting is not needed.

Comment: Haha I didn't even bother looking it up after your comment, I shouldn't be so trusting... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to change pixels to sp, you can see the whole thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263250/convert-pixels-to-sp)

```
public static float pixelsToSp(Context context, Float px) {
float scaledDensity = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
return px/scaledDensity;
```

}