# how to calculate the actual text size display?

Tags: android, text, textview, size

I have a textView in another view.

I want to calculate in runtime the actual display size of that text
and of its container.

If the text is too big to fit in the view I have few shorted text content alternatives.

I have read the textView doc, but it only shows `[setTextSize][1]`

how can i get the text size (in dp I guess ?) according to the actual screen.

(orientation, screen size, font size and so on)

Answer (score 2):

TextView actually has a `getTextSize()` method, which returns the font size in pixels for you. You can check [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getTextSize()) the documentation. Of course this pixel value will vary accordingly to the screen density of the device. If you want to convert that value for `dp` or `sp` on runtime, you can do the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6263430/2280692):

Pixels for SP:
`float sp = px / getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;`

Pixels for DP:
`float dp = px / getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;`